# render custom tag from REST API response

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have the following component MyComponent.vue:

```
<template>
  <div v-html="content"></div>
</template>

<script>
  import Vue from 'vue'
  import CustomComponent from 'CustomComponent.vue'
  Vue.use(CustomComponent)

  export default {
    name: `my-component`,
    computed: {
      content() {
        return this.$store.state.content
      }
    },

    asyncData({store, route: {params: {id}}}) {
      // here I fetch 'content' from REST API
      return store.dispatch('FETCH_CONTENT', {id})
    },


    // ...
  }
</script>
```

Where `this.$store.state.content` is html-string which I get from REST API. For example:

```
<custom-component data-count="1"></custom-component><p>some text</p>
```

`custom-component` tag is not rendered in may case.

Is it possible to render vue component from html-string which I get from REST API and if I use this string in `v-html`?

Comment: See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Async-Components

Comment: @Phil Adding of {'custom-component': () => import('CustomComponent.vue')} does not solve the issue. I think it related to that I use content in v-html

Comment: The problem with this is you're trying to bypass the compilation and mounting steps for the custom component which can cause larger issues with mutability and observance. It would be better to redesign your system so that the REST API returns pure data and the component renders it appropriately,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed Vue version with compiler in order to use the following example:

```
<div id="app">
  <h3>
    Vue component creator
  </h3>
  Template
  <textarea v-model="template"></textarea>
  Options
  <textarea v-model="options"></textarea>
  <button @click="create">
    Create component
  </button>
  <component :is="resultComponent"></component>
</div>


Vue.component('test',{
    template:'<div>It works!</div>'
})
new Vue({
    el:'#app',
  data(){
    return{
        stuff:'stuff',
      template:
`<div>
  <test></test>
  <b>{{stuff}}</b>
  <div v-for="n in 10">{{n}}</div>
</div>`,
            options:
`{
  data(){
    return {stuff:'awesome'}
  }
}`,
      resultComponent:undefined
    }
  },
  methods:{
    create(){
        let component = new Function('return' + this.options)()
      component.template = this.template
      this.resultComponent = component
    }   
  }
})
```

The fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Herteby/9syt27ja/